# Conexão do php com mysql

Tags: php, login

eu fiz um sistema de Login e cadastro porém estou com um problema, toda vez que eu termino de preencher o formulário e clico em enviar ele me da um erro assim

> "Warning: mysqli_connect(): (HY000/2005): Unknown MySQL server host
>   '?' (0) in /home/marmo504/cadastrar.liferedes.com.br/insert.php on
>   line 19 Connection failed: Unknown MySQL server host '?' (0)"

Ja fiz de tudo e não consegui resolver, poderiam me ajudar ?

Abaixo o código fonte:

```
<?php

  $servername = "#.br";
  $username = "#";
  $password = "#";
  $dbname = "#";

  // criar conexão
  $conn = mysqli_connect("servername", "username", "password",  "dbname");

  // checar conexão
  if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
  }

  $sql = "SELECT * FROM clientes";
  $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

  if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
      echo "- ID: " . $row["id"]. "<br> - Name: " . $row["firstname"]. " " . $row["lastname"]. "<br> - E-mail: " . $row["email"] . "<br> - Data de Nascimento: " . $row["dat_nasc"] . "<br> - Cidade: " . $row["cidade"] . "<br><br>";
    }
  } else {
    echo "0 results";
  }

 ?>

  <form action="#" method="link" style="margin-left:500px">
  <input type="submit" value="Voltar">
  </form>
```

Comment: cade a conexão?

Comment: // criar conexão
  $conn = mysqli_connect("servername", "username", "password",  "dbname");

  // checar conexão
  if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
  }

Comment: ``Unknown MySQL server host``.. não achou o servidor nesse IP/Porta

Comment: @CleberGriff Então não é nenhum erro de syntaxe?

Comment: uai man vc tem que por seus usuarios correto o erro ta no conecte.... seu local de desenvolvimento e online?

Comment: @Willian é online man, na real quando eu estava fazendo via xwamp estava funcionando, agora que subi pra hospedagem da esse erro

Comment: $servername = "#";
  $username = "#";
  $password = "#";
  $dbname = "#";

  // criar conexão
  $conn = mysqli_connect("servername", "username", "password",  "dbname");

  // checar conexão
  if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
  }

Comment: Eu coloquei os # pra não mostrar os dados más olha ai

Comment: Vc trocou o host pra localhost? Já que está na hospedagem, não é mais a url, já tá local

Comment: @WotonSampaio Sim

Comment: nao seria isso? o erro? "{$servername}" n esta axando as variavel

Comment: @Willian Não =x

Comment: cara tenta passa isso para pdo

Comment: $conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "senha",  "dbname"); tenta simples assim

Answer (score 0):

O erro aponta que seu `servidor` não existe, você está passando o `servidor` como `servername`.

O `servidor` que utilizamos para *teste* é o `localhost` ou `ip` `127.0.0.1`

Exemplo:
Seu *servidor* sendo `localhost`.

O *usuário* do seu banco de dados seja `root`.

A senha do usuário `root` seja `12345`.
E o nome do seu `banco de dados` seja *estoque*.

```
// Sua conexão ficaria assim

$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "12345",  "estoque");
```

Favor verificar se resolve.

[Referência](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.mysqli-connect.php)

Comment: Contínua dando o mesmo erro

Comment: Vi nos comentários acima que você disse que local funciona e online não. Você pode tentar no servername utiliza o ip em vez de localhost. Pega em sua hospedagem o ip para ver se resolve.

Answer (score -1):

Amigo, seu codigo está meio estranho, acredito que nessa parte você deveria passar as variáveis `$servername, $username, $password,  $dbname` . certo?

ficaria assim:

```
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password,  $dbname);
```

e claro, preencher essas variáveis com os valores reais do Server.
Exemplo:

```
$servername = "localhost";

$username = "root";

$password = "123456";

$dbname = "lojavirtual";
```

Espero ter ajudado!

Comment: Fiz oque você disse, continua do mesmo jeito =x

Comment: O que você colocou em $servername?

Comment: Acredito que o problema está nessa linha! talvez o server/url que você colocou seja desconhecido.

Comment: EU coloquei o seguinte link "br638.hostgator.com.br", que é o host que a hospedagem me passou para usar no host

Comment: mas em qual host dns ou sql?

Comment: sabe pq quando vc entra no br638.hostgator.com.br era pra te redirecionar pro phpmyadmin "normalmente"

Comment: Então, mas essa url é a que você entra no painel de controle não é? se for, não vai funcionar mesmo! procura no painel de controle no menu banco de dados, normalmente fica lá a url

Answer (score -2):

Esta linha precisa das variáveis corretas do PHP

```
$conn = mysqli_connect("servername", "username", "password",  "dbname");
```

fica

```
$conn = mysqli_connect("$servername", "$username", "$password",  "$dbname");
```

Você tem certeza que o banco está criado e existe um usuário com acesso a ele?

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).